# paucis exceptis qui in praesidio civitatis morabantur, caeteros pro libero detractantes arbitrio

Tags: medieval-latin

This paragraph belongs to William of Tyre.William is an important historian about the Crusades. William's work translated to English magnificently. But I want to examine this sentence: **paucis exceptis qui in praesidio civitatis morabantur, caeteros pro libero detractantes arbitrio.**

**in this sentence "their own good pleasure" what is the meaning of? positive or negative means? thank you for your help –**

especially " Erat autem praedicta civitas Christianos habens habitatores, paucis exceptis qui in praesidio civitatis morabantur, caeteros pro libero detractantes arbitrio." this sentence translate from Latin to English: With a few exceptions, the inhabitants of this city were Christians. The infidels were in possession of the citadel, however, treated the rest of population according to **THEİR OWN GOOD PLEASURE**. Question: Have the same meaning especially "**their own good pleasure" with "pro libero detractantes arbitrio**"?

THANK YOU

The whole Sentence:
Interea dum circa partes Edessanas trans Euphratem dominus ita desudat Balduinus, major exercitus, ut praemissum est, per abrupta montium et vallium devexa, Maresiam usque pervenerat. Erat autem praedicta civitas Christianos habens habitatores, **paucis exceptis qui in praesidio civitatis morabantur, caeteros pro *libero detractantes arbitrio.*** Hi vero audito nostrorum adventu, perterriti, clam aufugerant, urbem solis fidelibus relinquentes; ad quam postquam Deo devotus pervenit exercitus, ante urbis moenia, in pascuis virentibus castrametati sunt, violentiam inferri civibus omnino prohibentes.

Comment: Can you explain what it is about that sentence you want examined?

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you clarified your question. Are you looking for a translation, an analysis, a gloss, or something else?

Comment: especially " Erat autem praedicta civitas Christianos habens habitatores, paucis exceptis qui in praesidio civitatis morabantur, caeteros pro libero detractantes arbitrio."  this sentence translate from Latin to English: With a few exceptions, the inhabitants of this city were Christians. The infidels were in possession of the citadel, however, treated the rest of population according to THEİR OWN GOOD PLEASURE.  Question: Have the same meaning especially "their own good pleasure" with "pro libero detractantes arbitrio"?

Comment: in this sentence "their own good pleasure" what is the meaning of? positive or negative means? thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*According to their own good pleasure* should mean "arbitrarily", without heeding any specific rules. Usually, that is bad, and people are treated unfairly, without respect for any laws or moral rules. *Pro libero arbitrio* should mean "according to free judgement" if you translate it literally, so the translation makes sense.